# Does "significant improvement connection" seem ok?

Tags: grammaticality

Is this sentence a legal sentence in English?

> Company has required significant improvement connection between
>   devices and IT systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Company has required significant improvement connection between devices and IT systems.

This would mean that a connection has to be made to improvements between devices and systems.

Even in very advanced management-speak, that does not begin to make sense.

I suspect that what was required was a an improvement of the (existing) connection.

That would be a **connection improvement**.

Think of a raise in salary, which is a **salary raise**, not a "raise salary". Or the transfer of money, which would be a **money transfer**, not a "transfer money".

As for *company has required*, this sounds a bit weird, but it might be the lack of context. I would suggest something like:

> The company requires a significant connection improvement between devices and IT systems.

(I also added an indefinite article)

Comment: Do you mean "The company requires **a** significant connection improvement between devices and IT systems"?

Comment: I think the more likely error is a missing “in”. It would make sense as “[Company] has required significant improvement **[in]** connection between devices and IT systems.”

Comment: Then it would be _in the_ connection, or an improvement _of the_ connection. But those are indeed also possibilities. _A connection improvement_ is more succinct though :)